# Do custom allocators in STL only allocate the actual data?

Tags: c++, stl

Let's say I create a linked list in STL:

```
list<int, my_allocator<int> > data;
```

Then I can use a more efficient allocator, let's say a memory pool. But doesn't the list need to allocate internal memory like forward and backward pointers to traverse the list? How will these be allocated? Using normal `new` or somehow using `my_allocator`?

Comment: Do you mean the STL or the C++ Standard Library implementation that ships with your chosen toolchain? And which one is that?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, what? (+1 to the question)

Comment: @avakar The STL was originally a sgi project. Since then there have been several implementations of the STL (such as STLport) and much of it has been added to the standard library as defined by the committee, albeit with a few changes. All of which leaves *"STL"* a wee bit ambiguous in ways that might affect this question.

Comment: @dmckee: A bit ambiguous, perhaps. But it's hard to say that it's worth downvoting. People use STL and C++ standard library synonymously; downvoting them for it won't stop them.

Comment: @Ben: I added some examples from GCC 4.6.2.

Comment: Who knows who downvoted. It wasn't me, but Tomalak's comment is reasonable.

Comment: Being pedantic over the difference between STL and C++ Standard Library is quite pointless. The reality is that a very large chunk of the useful Standard is derived quite directly from the STL. Moreover, the STL itself is very old now and nobody will be using the actual, original, STL.

Comment: I bother of correct use of terminology and abbreviations myself, and sometimes correct (and annoy) others about that, and I don't see what this debate is all about. The OP used the abbreviation "STL" correctly: **not as a synonym for "C++ standard library"**, but to mean the containers, iterators, algorithms and related utility components, whose design was taken almost completely from he original HP STL design, collectively called **"Standard Template Library"**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The container does indeed repurpose your allocator to allocate its own book-keeping material. (Not that it would matter for a `std::list`, but it's true in general.*) This is why the standard allocator requirements mandate the existence of the `rebind` template:

```
typedef typename Alloc::template rebind<MyInternalStuff>::other internal_allocator;
```

If your allocator is `Alloc = my_allocator<T>`, then `internal_allocator` becomes `my_allocator<MyInternalStuff>`.

I believe that this was one of the gripes that Electronic Arts had with the C++ standard library, which is why their [EASTL](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html) library uses a different convention for allocators that offers tighter control.

<sub>*) Typically, each node will be one monolithic object of some type `Node<T>`, so I suppose `std::list<T, Alloc>` *only* ever uses `Alloc::rebind<Node<T>>::other` as an allocator.</sub>

[Sorry for the multiple edits; I had the output mangled up and didn't interpret it correctly; I now went and printed each container separately and fixed the output up accordingly. `std::list` does indeed only require *one* allocator.]

---

**Update:** Just for giggles, I wrote a little demangling-allocator which prints its own typename upon construction. Here's the input:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <set>
#include <deque>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "----- unordered_map<int, double> -----------" << std::endl;
  std::unordered_map<int, double, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, funky_allocator<std::pair<const int, double>>> m { {1, 1.2} };
  std::cout << "----- set<int> -----------------------------" << std::endl;
  std::set<int, std::less<int>, funky_allocator<int>> s;
  std::cout << "----- deque<int> ---------------------------" << std::endl;
  std::deque<int, funky_allocator<int>> d;
  std::cout << "----- list<int> ----------------------------" << std::endl;
  std::list<int, funky_allocator<int>> l;
  std::cout << "----- vector<int> --------------------------" << std::endl;
  std::vector<int, funky_allocator<int>> c;
  std::cout << "----- map<int, bool> -----------------------" << std::endl;
  std::map<int, bool, std::less<int>, funky_allocator<std::pair<const int, bool>>> n { { 1, true } };
}
```

And here the output:

```
----- unordered_map<int, double> -----------
Default-construct: funky_allocator<std::pair<int const, double> >
Copy-construct:    funky_allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<int const, double>, false> >
Copy-construct:    funky_allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<int const, double>, false>*>

----- set<int> -----------------------------
Default-construct: funky_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<int> >

----- deque<int> ---------------------------
Default-construct: funky_allocator<int>
Copy-construct:    funky_allocator<int*>

----- list<int> ----------------------------
Default-construct: funky_allocator<std::_List_node<int> >

----- vector<int> --------------------------
Default-construct: funky_allocator<int>

----- map<int, bool> -----------------------
Default-construct: funky_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, bool> > >
```

The details vary depending on which constructor is used: Containers like `set` and `map` might only construct the "correct" allocator in some invocation, while in another they may construct an object of the specified allocator first. Either way, the specified allocator never gets used at all for a couple of containers, and *only* the rebound version is used.

Comment: @avakar: You're right, I just noticed that! In fact, I just wrote my own demangling allocator that prints its own class name upon instantiation to check how many different allocators some popular containers require.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Updated with some hard evidence.

Comment: This is also fun to use with `shared_ptr<T>(new T, default_delete<T>(), funky_allocator<T>())` and `allocate_shared<T>(funky_allocator<T>())`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also read elsewhere that C++11 supports allocators with state -- good news! I was able to increase the map<> creation time 100 times and deallocation time 10000 times with my simple memory pool.